# Advice on Electronic Engineering Internships

Tags: dc

I'm a student majoring in Electronic Engineering. I'm interested in applying for an internship this summer. I have another semester before I'll be halfway through the program. Therefore, I'm concerned that applying for an internship right now is to early. Courses that I have completed and currently taking that are program related are as follows.

Currently Taking:
ECET-110 Electronic Circuits & Devices I w/ LAB

Completed Course Work:
COMP-122 (Structured Programming w/ LAB),
MATH-190 (Pre-Calculus), 
ECET-100 (Introduction to Electronics and Computer Engineering w/ LAB)

Prior Education:
A.S. in Welding Technology

I'm a very motivated and committed student. I'm maintaining a perfect 4.0 GPA and conducting out of class research and projects on my own time. Applying for an internship and having a good mentor as a intern is important to me. **Do I stay focused on my course work and be patient until I'm halfway through the program?** Thank you for any information and guidance that you have.

Answer (score 2):

When recruiting EE interns, I focus more on the applicant's specific skill set and motivation rather than an arbitrary number of years in school.  It sounds like you're very driven and have the benefit of having already completed your AS degree.  Both of these factors will play in your favor.

I'd definitely recommend that you apply for internships this year.  I've found that the more motivated students start looking for summer positions in the winter, while less motivated students start looking in late spring.  In short, you're starting to think about this at the right time.

Find a few companies that look like a good fit for your interests, write a personalized cover letter ("I'd love to intern at your company because..."), and see what happens.  The worst they can say is "no", and I'd wager that your drive will be very attractive to a number of potential employers.

Best of luck!